# How to fix Compile error: expected End Sub?

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

I am trying, when a line of information is added to one of my sheets, to automatically add that line to a different sheet in the same workbook.

I found this code and tweaked it a little:

```
Sub addrow()

Public Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

    Set sourcebook = ThisWorkbook
    Set sourcesheet = sourcebook.Worksheets("sheet1")

    Set targetbook = ThisWorkbook
    Set targetsheet = targetbook.Worksheets("sheet10")

    If sourcesheet.Cells(198, 16).Value = "Auto" Or _
        sourcesheet.Cells(198, 16).Value = "Connect" Or _
        sourcesheet.Cells(198, 16).Value = "Multiple*" Or _
        sourcesheet.Cells(198, 16).Value = "Property" Or _
        sourcesheet.Cells(198, 16).Value = "Umbrella" Or _
        sourcesheet.Cells(198, 16).Value = "WC" Then
        GoTo link
    Else
        GoTo insertion
    End If

    insertion: targetsheet.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Rows(198).EntireRow.Insert

    sourcesheet.Activate

link:
    'targetsheet.Cells(194, targetsheet.Range("initial response").Column) = sourcesheet.Cells(198, 16).Value
    targetsheet.Cells(194, 16) = sourcesheet.Cells(198, 16).Value

    targetsheet.Cells(194, 16) = sourcesheet.Cells(198, 16).Value

End Sub
```

I get the error message "Compile Error: Expected End Sub" and it highlights that first line of code- Sub addrow(). When I try taking this line out, VBA requires me to create a new macro when I try and run it, which then adds that line back in, and I am back to square one.

Comment: You have Sub addrow() and then immediately Public Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range) -- subroutines cannot overlap, and every Sub should have a matching End Sub, hence this error. Either remove Sub addrow() and make sure that workshett_change() is actually usable, or if you are manually running the macro then remove the worksheet_change() line, but keep Sub addrow(). Hope that helps.
P.S.: please no ALL CAPS in messages.

Answer (score 4):

Focus on first 3 lines.  You have two `Sub` declarations there. Keep only one.
Perhaps remove line

```vb
Public Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
```

I think you should remove this line and not the other one because it seems to be forgotten from some previous work. Its parameter `target` is not used in the code and what your code does better fits with name `addrow` than with `worksheet_change`.

This is your code refactored:

- variable names keep VBA naming convention
- blocks of code rearranged so gotos and labels could be excluded

.

```vb
Sub AddRow()

    Set SourceBook = ThisWorkbook
    Set SourceSheet = SourceBook.Worksheets("sheet1")

    Set TargetBook = ThisWorkbook
    Set TargetSheet = TargetBook.Worksheets("sheet10")

    If Not (SourceSheet.Cells(198, 16).Value = "Auto"
            Or SourceSheet.Cells(198, 16).Value = "Connect"
            Or SourceSheet.Cells(198, 16).Value = "Multiple*"
            Or SourceSheet.Cells(198, 16).Value = "Property"
            Or SourceSheet.Cells(198, 16).Value = "Umbrella"
            Or SourceSheet.Cells(198, 16).Value = "WC") Then
        TargetSheet.Activate
        ActiveSheet.Rows(198).EntireRow.Insert
        SourceSheet.Activate
    End If

    'TargetSheet.Cells(194, TargetSheet.Range("initial response").Column) = SourceSheet.Cells(198, 16).Value
    TargetSheet.Cells(194, 16) = SourceSheet.Cells(198, 16).Value
    TargetSheet.Cells(194, 16) = SourceSheet.Cells(198, 16).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Good news- the compile error was fixed after i removed the Public Sub line as you said. Now I am getting the error- "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range". I googled and it seems that I didn't correctly refer to a range?

Comment: @mfrank7114 – there are many subscripts used in your code. At which one the error occurs? Focus on that one. Try debugging: (1) move caret to first row (`Sub ...`)  (2) Press **F9** to set a breakpoint. (3) Run your program, it stops at the breakpoint. (4) Keep pressing **F8** to walk step by step down your program and observe its steps. You can also view variables etc. See *Debug* menu during stepping.

Answer (score -2):

```
Private Sub CMDSAVE_CLICK()
Dim WORDAPP As word.Application
Dim worddoc As word.document
Dim filename
filename = Range("c2").Value
Sheets("ÝÇ˜ÊæÑ").Range("a1:k26").Select
Selection.Copy
Set WORDAPP = CreateObject("word.application")
Set worddec = WORDAPP.documents.Add
WORDAPP.Selection.pasteexeeltabele False, False, False
filename = "f:\" & filename
wordpec.Close
WORDAPP.Quit
Set wordpic = Nothing
Set WORDAPP = Nothing
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: You might want to add an explanation to your answer, so reader can understand why this is a good solution to the question. Use the [edit] button.